# Does Hilbert $C^*$-modules have orthonormal basis?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, hilbert-modules

Let $E$ be a (right) Hilbert $A$-module where $A$ is **unital** $C^*$-algebra. I call a subset $S$ of $E$ to orthonormal if $\langle x,x\rangle=1$ ($1$ denotes the unit in $A$) for all $x\in S$ and $\langle x,y\rangle=0$ for all $x\ne y$. Then Zorn's lemma guarantees the existence of maximal orthonormal set in $E$. Let $\{e_i\}$ be a maximal orthonormal set. My question is- Does the following identity hold for $x\in E$? $$x=\sum\limits_{i\in I}e_i\langle e_i,x\rangle$$

If I know that the series $\sum\limits_{i\in I}e_i\langle e_i,x\rangle$ converges in $E$, then the above equality holds, because then $x-\sum\limits_{i\in I}e_i\langle e_i,x\rangle$ will be orthogonal to $e_j$ for all $j$, hence $x=\sum\limits_{i\in I}e_i\langle e_i,x\rangle$.

I can prove that $\left\langle x-\sum\limits_{i\in I'}e_i\langle e_i,x\rangle,x-\sum\limits_{i\in I'}e_i\langle e_i,x\rangle\right\rangle\ge0\implies |x|^2\ge\sum\limits_{i\in I'}|\langle e_i,x\rangle|^2$ for any finite $I'\subseteq I$.

Does that imply the series $\sum\limits_{i\in I}e_i\langle e_i,x\rangle$ converge in $E$? Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The inequality $|x|^2 \geqslant \sum_{i\in I'} |\langle e_i,x\rangle|^2$ implies that there are at most countably many $i\in I$ such that $\langle e_i,x\rangle\neq 0$. If it's finite, then you're done. Otherwise you can enumerate it as $(i_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and show that $\langle \sum_{n=1}^N e_{i_n}\langle e_{i_n}, x\rangle$ is Cauchy, which you can do by considering finite subsets of $I$ and your inequality should help. As you said, once you have convergence *in some order*, it must be convergence to $x$, so order doesn't matter.

Comment: You may also want to assume that $E$ is a *full* Hilbert module, otherwise there may be no orthonormal sets.

Comment: @bangs, For Hilbert spaces, where the inner product takes values in $\Bbb{C}$, I can understand. If $\langle e_i,x\rangle\ne0$, then it might not be true that $\langle e_i,x\rangle\ge \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Even though I assume $\{e_i\}$ to be countable $\lVert S_n-S_m\rVert^2=\lVert\sum\limits_{i={m+1}}^n|\langle e_i,x\rangle|^2\rVert$, then how to make this quantity small I may not have the series $\sum\lVert\langle e_i,x\rangle\rVert^2$ to be convergent. For Hilbert spaces, these are obvious. Can you please just let me know where I'm missing the point?

Comment: @Aweygan Okay, you mean existence of unit vector (i.e. $\langle x,x\rangle=1$) is a issue. Yes, I didn't notice that. If $E$ is full, then how can I ensure that?

Comment: That is a good point.  I think one actually needs the $C^*$-algebra $A$ to be simple and purely infinite to ensure the existence of a unit vector in any Hilbert $A$-module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counter-example for real C*-algebras.  There are similar examples for complex ones too, but the phenomenon is
easier to understand in the real case.

Consider the real C*-algebra $C(S^2)$ formed by all real-valued functions on the 2-sphere $S^2$.  Also consider the
vector space $E$ formed by all continuous vector fields on $S^2$ (i.e. continuous sections of the tangent vector bundle
$TS^2$).

Pointwise multiplying vector fields  by  continuous functions yields a natural $C(S^2)$ module structure
on $E$.  Moreover, providing each tangent space $T_pS^2$ with its standard inner-product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle _p$ (i.e.,
considering $S^2$ with its standard Riemannian structure), we can define a $C(S^2)$ valued inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle _{C(S^2)}$
on $E$, namely
$$
  \langle \xi , \eta \rangle _{C(S^2)}(p) =   \langle \xi (p), \eta (p)\rangle _p, \quad (\xi ,\eta \in E, \  p\in S^2).
  $$

Now, it is not hard to see that if $\{e_i\}_i$  is an orthonormal basis for $E$, then, for each $p$ in $S^2$, one has
that
$\{e_i(x)\}_i$  will be an orthonormal basis for $T_pS^2$, but this contradicts the fact that the tangent bundle
of  $S^2$ is not trivial!

In fact it is even impossible to find a single non-vanishing vector field (see the Hairy Ball theorem of algebraic
topology).  In the context of the above comments, this says that indeed  there is no "unit vector" in this Hilbert module.